# TSQL So weird, dividing doesn't work in select (but * - + works fine), but only for one column

Tags: t-sql

I have so weird issue:

```
select ****
COALESCE(Customers / (NULLIF(Visitors,0)),0) AS CR
```

for 3/3 returns 1
for 157/2 returns 0 
or any other non 1 will return 0.

The CR is decimal(8,2) and for all other columns the same line is working (with mix of different columns)

I have tried + - *, all works as should, however as soon I use division it won't return a value unless is one.

What is going on ??? Why dividing doesn't work, while all other arithmetic functions works just fine. Looks like it won't return decimals...

Comment: Hmm works fine with other selects, but will try it ! Hmm gives weird results (only in INT + X.00), however results are totally off) i.e 2 / 157 = 2 ?? Or  5 / 14 = 5 ?

Comment: Divide by zero is a problem.  CR is an alias and cannot have a type.  Integer division will return an integer.

Comment: CR is a name of a column, without alias it doesn't work either. 
Just for formality

 ,COALESCE((NULLIF(TotalVisitors,0) / NULLIF(New,0)),0) AS XXX  works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't replicate your results, but perhaps this will help clarify.

**Example**

```
Declare @T table (Customers int,Visitors int)
Insert Into @T values
(2,157),
(5,14),
(2,0),
(null,25),
(15,null)

select CR = IsNull((Customers+0.0) / nullif(Visitors,0),0)
 From  @T
```

Returns

```
CR
0.012738853503
0.357142857142
0.000000000000
0.000000000000
0.000000000000
```

Comment: This works, however I cannot understand why it works fine on different select. Well I understand it has something got do with decimal places and precision, and a fact that one of columns is already in decimal ;), anyway thank you for an example. Now I know :)

Comment: @mike86 At a complete loss   2 / 157 does not = 2 .  Did you have another coalesce baked in there?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti , interesting trick to convert the integer to numeric. How does the implicit conversion of adding 0.0 perform compared to explicit conversion?

Comment: @AnthonyHancock Good question.  I'd imagine virtually no difference because both ways, there is a conversion going on.  However, many folks prefer the explicit/precision.  Latter I'll run benchmarks later and let you know if there is a performance hit either way

Comment: @mike86 If you had posted sample data to fail maybe you could have received and answer.

Comment: @AnthonyHancock Not a true scientific test.   100,000 records, 7 runs each excluding high and low.  Implicit (+0.0) Average 61.7MS.  Explicit ( decimal(10,4) ) Average 71.4MS

Comment: @JohnCappelletti interesting that implicit seems faster than explicit.Were you testing some kind of aggregate or actually outputting all 100k rows?

Comment: @AnthonyHancock All 100K to a temp table.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti also not very scientific and you might have some holes to poke in the method, but tested SUM aggregation of integer column against table with about 115 mil records doing the same 7 runs after caching the plan and explicit was averaging 10 seconds where implicit was averaging 15, so there might be a question of scaling but 5 seconds isn't exactly a lot of time to lose.

Comment: @AnthonyHancock 5 seconds is a long time to wait after a web page click  :)  Still a good question and something to be sensitive to in the future.